# InsertAllOnSubmit in LinqToEntities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

What's the Method to `InsertAllonSubmit` in `LinqToEntities`.
I am getting a result using where condition from one table.
Now I need to Insert all records at a time into another table with out using `for-loop` in Linq To Entities.
Is that Possible like : `Insert into (Select *)` in SQL?

Now I need to loop it and `Add()`.

```
Int64 groupid = Convert.ToInt64(EmailGroupId);

var data = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_LIST
            where xx.EMAIL_GROUP_ID == groupid
            select xx).ToList();                   


data.ForEach(t2e => VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST.Add(new SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
{
    EMAILID = t2e.EMAILID
}));
```

Comment: Could you maybe throw in some code. As an example of what you need. It would help.

Comment: but that code is not working :(

Comment: Are you calling `VDC.SaveChanges();` ?

Comment: @Habib Thank you for adding my answer as a comment 20 minutes later.

Comment: that works,but even it is looping records.I want a method like "InsertAllonSubmit"

Answer (score 0):

Linq-to-Entities does not provide a `InsertAllOnSubmit`-method. Instead you invoke `SaveChanges()` on your `context`-instance to save all changes. This will update all changed entities, insert all added entities and deletes all removed entities that are attached to this context.